# Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Tags: mysql, sql

**IMPORTANTE** - Cabe destacar que el error lo puedo solucionar, pero es un trabajo que consume demasiado tiempo. Es una revisión manual de cada tabla, vista, procedimiento. Y hay que reescribir cada uno, luego de haber corregido las tablas.

---

Necesito ayuda solventando este problema.

Recientemente me he topado con este problema de collations, en mi base de datos mysql. Y he corregido TODAS, repito **HE CORREGIDO TODAS LAS TABLAS MANUALMENTE**, campo por campo, para que todas tengan el mismo collation, **y esto no resuelve el problema.**

Ahora, lo que pienso, es que el problema no radica en el collation de las tablas, o de la base de datos. Sino, en las vistas, y procedimientos.
Actualmente, el problema se da entre un procedimiento que registra diferentes vistas, y genera un resultado. Es durante este procedimiento almacenado, que ocurre este error. Lamentablemente el error no es descriptivo,solo dice que ocurre durante una operación '='.

Por ahora, uso esto para revisar los collations de las tablas:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME,
    TABLE_COLLATION
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name';
```

Lo que me entrega un listado, con todas las tablas, y todas con el mismo collation. El problema, es que a pesar de listar las vistas, no muestra el collation de la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidentemente la collation configurada en tu base de datos `utf8mb4_*`

Entonces, ¿por qué sucede que al crear una vista los campos/columnas se crean utilizando otra collation?

Se debe a que cada charset tiene una collation por defecto.

Como en tu caso el charset de tu base de datos es `utf8mb4`, para averiguar cual es la collation por defecto podes ejecutas la siguiente consulta:

```sql
SHOW COLLATION WHERE Charset = 'utf8mb4';
```

Vas a obtener un resultado similar a este:

```
+----------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+---------------+
| Collation                  | Charset | Id  | Default | Compiled | Sortlen | Pad_attribute |
+----------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+---------------+
| utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci         | utf8mb4 | 255 | Yes     | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_0900_as_ci         | utf8mb4 | 305 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_0900_as_cs         | utf8mb4 | 278 |         | Yes      |       0 | NO PAD        |
...
```

Como se puede ver en la columna `Default`, la collation por defecto es `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` y es ésta la que se le va a asignar a las columnas de tus vistas.

Ahora, ¿cómo hacemos para que las columnas se creen con la collation correcta?

Al crear las vistas y por cada columna que necesites, utilizando `COLLATE` la indicas.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `mi_vista` AS 
SELECT 
  CONVERT(nombre_columna USING utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci AS nombre_columna
FROM nombre_tabla;
```

**PD**: Utilizar `CONVERT([COL_NAME] USING [CHARSET])` es necesario solo si estas cambiando a un charset distinto, por ejemplo, de `latin1` a `utf8mb4`

Finalmente, si necesitas saber qué columnas de que tablas tiene una collation distinta a la que necesitas, podes ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '[NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS]' # reemplazar
    AND COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL
    AND COLLATION_NAME != '[NOMBRE_COLLATION]'; # reemplazar
```

Comment: Y si la base de datos la creé con un collation diferente, entonces no importa? el default siempre es ´utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci´ ?. Y gracias por la respuesta, bien completa y detallada.

Comment: @Excorpion, actualicé mi respuesta. Espero ahora esté más claro.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Agrego, se puede ampliar la consulta a las funciones y procedimientos almacenados ?

Comment: @Excorpion, no entiendo la pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que esperarías obtener?

Comment: Simplificarme la vida en lo posible jaja. No pero gracias, me has ayudado mucho con esto. Ignora la última pregunta, ya encontré solución.